# Intellij Tomcat fails to deploy artifact

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, deployment, artifact

I ran my Web Apps on Tomcat, and they can run successfully. However, after my computer was configured with another company's domain, I can not deploy my app on Tomcat anymore. The server console (a hello world web app) is shown as follows:

```
10-Apr-2017 17:42:04.102 Info [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.13
10-Apr-2017 17:42:04.113 Info [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
10-Apr-2017 17:42:04.125 Info [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
10-Apr-2017 17:42:04.132 Info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 80 ms
Connected to server
[2017-04-10 05:42:04,349] Artifact 2017.04.10-testHelloWorld:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2017-04-10 05:42:04,408] Artifact 2017.04.10-testHelloWorld:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
10-Apr-2017 17:42:14.123 Info [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\z674149\.IntelliJIdea2016.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_2017_04_10-testHelloWorld\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
10-Apr-2017 17:42:17.663 Info [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
10-Apr-2017 17:42:17.811 Info [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\z674149\.IntelliJIdea2016.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_2017_04_10-testHelloWorld\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml has finished in 3,687 ms
```

My development environments:

1. Java 8
2. Intellij 2016.1.2 (build 145.972)
3. Tomcat 8.5.13
4. Windows 7

I have tried several methods:

1. Re-install Tomcat and Intellij;
2. Re-config $JAVA_HOME, $CATALINA_HOME and so on;
3. Create and add a new Artifact on Intellij.

This problem puzzles me heavily. Kindly Help me out please.

Comment: See if https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171174 helps.

Comment: @CrazyCoder It DOES help!!! Thanks a lot.